# Simulating Key Press event using Python for Linux

Tags: python, linux, key, keypress, simulate

I am writing a script to automate running a particular model. When the model fails, it waits for a user input (Enter key). I can detect when the model has failed, but I am not able to use python (on linux) to simulate a key press event. Windows has the SendKeys library to do this but I was wondering if there is a similar library for python on linux.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the "model" is running graphically (with the X window system), the already-suggested [xsendkey](http://people.csail.mit.edu/adonovan/hacks/xsendkey.html) is a possibility, or [xsendkeycode](http://linux.die.net/man/8/xsendkeycode).  If it's running textually (in a terminal window), then [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect).

Comment: Hi!

A corollary:
While using pexpect, the following simple program doesn't seem to work for me:
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('ls')
fout = file('output.txt', 'w')
child.logfile = fout

I.e, output.txt is created but is empty when I cat it.

pexpect is installed fine, since I can run the samples supplied with the program.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!
thanks!

Comment: The links to `xsendkey` and `xsendkeycode` are dead.

Comment: @hazzey here is a fork that works great: https://github.com/kyoto/sendkeys The xsendkey program is awesome to bypass restrictions when a simple copy-paste is not allowed and when you have to write tags followed by a validation with the enter / return key, like on Tumblr (a JavaScript hack would have been more complicated)

Answer (score 15):

Have a look at this https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput
its cross-platform control for mouse and keyboard in python

Keyboard control works on X11(linux) and Windows systems. But no mac support(when i wrote this answer).

```
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard
k = PyKeyboard()

# To Create an Alt+Tab combo
k.press_key(k.alt_key)
k.tap_key(k.tab_key)
k.release_key(k.alt_key)
```

Comment: Do you know how to 'tap' the space key?

Comment: Take a look at these projs, space key must be mapped to ' '(string with space in it)
https://github.com/Narengowda/web-mouse/blob/master/web_mouse/mouse_wsh.py#L62
https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput/blob/master/pykeyboard/x11.py#L28

Comment: I came up with something like `k.tab_key(k.keypad_keys['Space'])` but it doesn't work. It is hard for me to understand the project documentation. Could you please help?

Comment: Did you try key_board.type_string(' ') ?

Answer (score 10):

A more low-level approach would be to create an `uinput` device from which you would then inject input events into the linux input subsystem. Consider the following libraries:

- [python-uinput](http://tjjr.fi/sw/python-uinput/)
- [evdev](https://github.com/gvalkov/python-evdev)

Example of sending `<enter>` with the latter:

```
from evdev import uinput, ecodes as e

with uinput.UInput() as ui:
     ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.KEY_ENTER, 1)
     ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.KEY_ENTER, 0)
     ui.syn()
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [PyAutoGui](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyAutoGUI). It's ridiculously simple to use, it's cross-platform and it's for Python 3 and 2.

In the linked page are listed the dependences and some code examples.

Answer (score 1):

http://people.csail.mit.edu/adonovan/hacks/xsendkey.html

Comment: You can obviously take a look at the rather simple code of xsendkey and search for the corresponding calls in the Xlib binding for python.

Answer (score 0):

As many of the solutions I have found in this and in another [well ranked SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714072/simulate-keystroke-in-linux-with-python) were either deprecated ([PyUserInput](https://github.com/PyUserInput/PyUserInput)) or using [evdev](https://github.com/gvalkov/python-evdev), which failed (`UInputError: "/dev/uinput" cannot be opened for writing`) the simplest solution for me using Linux was [pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html). One example directly from their docs:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

# Press and release space
keyboard.press(Key.space)
keyboard.release(Key.space)

# Type a lower case A; this will work even if no key on the
# physical keyboard is labelled 'A'
keyboard.press('a')
keyboard.release('a')

# Type two upper case As
keyboard.press('A')
keyboard.release('A')
with keyboard.pressed(Key.shift):
    keyboard.press('a')
    keyboard.release('a')

# Type 'Hello World' using the shortcut type method
keyboard.type('Hello World')
```

It worked like a charm!