# Simulate keystroke in Linux with Python

Tags: python, linux, simulation, keystroke

How can I simulate a keystroke in python? I also want to press multiple keys simultaneously.

Something like:

```
keystroke('CTRL+F4')
```

or

```
keystroke('Shift+A')
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this? Also, under which environment? Command line? Graphical Desktop?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Although it's specific to X, you can install the xautomation package (`apt-get install xautomation` on Debian-based systems) and use `xte` to simulate keypresses, e.g.:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

control_f4_sequence = '''keydown Control_L
key F4
keyup Control_L
'''

shift_a_sequence = '''keydown Shift_L
key A
keyup Shift_L
'''

def keypress(sequence):
    p = Popen(['xte'], stdin=PIPE)
    p.communicate(input=sequence)

keypress(shift_a_sequence)
keypress(control_f4_sequence)
```

Comment: How can I send keys to the shell?

Answer (score 19):

Consider [python-uinput](http://tjjr.fi/sw/python-uinput/) and [evdev](http://packages.python.org/evdev/). Example of `shift+a` with the latter:

```
from evdev import uinput, ecodes as e

with uinput.UInput() as ui:
    ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.KEY_LEFTSHIFT, 1)
    ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.KEY_A, 1)
    ui.syn()
```

Comment: I tried similar code, it is exeuted because I see in system log that a new virtual input device was created but the keystrokes do not appear in X? Any special thing can be done so the keys are received by X server?

Comment: The links are dead

Comment: This is great! Note that 1 is a keydown event and 0 is keyup, so if you wanted to simulate a pressing and releasing a key more than once, you would need to place something like the following lines in a loop: 
`ui.write(ecodes.EV_KEY, ecodes.KEY_DOWN, 1)   #key down`
`ui.write(ecodes.EV_KEY, ecodes.KEY_DOWN, 0)   #key up`
`ui.syn()`

Comment: it gave me this error:
`UInputError: "/dev/uinput" cannot be opened for writing`
Any suggestion?

Comment: Adding `KERNEL=="uinput", MODE="0666` to the top of /etc/udev/rules.d/50-rogdrv.rules and reloading rules solves the problem" ([github issue](https://github.com/kyokenn/rogdrv/issues/5))

You can reload udev rules like this 
`# udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger`
([source](https://newbedev.com/how-to-reload-udev-rules-without-reboot))

Comment: The example given only requires [evdev](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).  After I did `pip install evdev`, I pasted the example into a python3 interpreter.  It worked straight away. It may have helped that I already had the uinput kernel module loaded.- `modprobe uinput`.

Answer (score 15):

[python-uinput](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-uinput):

> Pythonic API to Linux uinput kernel module...
>
> Python-uinput is Python interface to Linux uinput kernel module which allows attaching userspace device drivers into kernel. In practice, Python-uinput makes it dead simple to create virtual joysticks, keyboards and mice for generating arbitrary input events programmatically...

Comment: Can i emit in lowercase? please an example!!

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 4):

If you plan to use it on Linux, try [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library.
For multiple keys you will need to use hotkey, e.g.:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')  # ctrl-c to copy
```

For me it worked - see here:
[How to pass a keystroke (ALT+TAB) using Popen.communicate (on Linux)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48449895/how-to-pass-a-keystroke-alttab-using-popen-communicate-on-linux/48455097#48455097)

Comment: Works on windows as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows, use [Sendkeys](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/SendKeys) and if on Linux, try out the suggestion [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575528/simulating-key-press-event-using-python-for-linux/2576118#2576118) for xsendkeys or pexpect.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution I have found was using [pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html). You could do the following:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()
with keyboard.pressed(Key.ctrl):
   keyboard.press(Key.f4)
   keyboard.release(Key.f4)
```