# How to automate a keystroke in python

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, squish

I am Automating a GUI application using Squish Automation tool. The environment I am using is Ubuntu. My Automation code is in Python. I need to hit keystroke "D" to launch a debug console on my GUI to automate it. How can I write a python code that simulates the keystroke hit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python simulate keydown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906925/python-simulate-keydown)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulate keystroke in Linux with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714072/simulate-keystroke-in-linux-with-python)

Answer (score 2):

try with `nativeType("D")`, or take a look at: http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/