# PyGame key.get_pressed method not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, keyboard-events

My code is here:

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()
while 1:
    print(True in pg.key.get_pressed())
```

`key.get_pressed` returns a tuple of booleans, one for each key on the keyboard.  `True in` should check to see if any of them are true, but the result is always `False`  What am I doing wrong?

If necessary, I am using python 3.4 and am on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`key.get_pressed()` needs a window to work, so you should create one with

```
pg.display.set_mode((100,100)) # or whatever size you want
```

first.

Comment: Oh, that's too bad, I wanted to use it in the command prompt window.  msvcrt's getch acts really strangely with arrow keys (it gives both 224 and the arrow key's code, not just one making it a little annoying to deal with).  Do you know any other way to keyboard input?

Comment: Maybe one of the following can help you: [How to accept keypress in command line python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693256/) [Python read a single character from the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/) [Python cross-platform listening for keypresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044073)

Comment: I ended up getting a windows port of the curses module.  It works well.  Thanks for your help.