# Inhibit screensaver with Python

Tags: python, linux, screensaver, xorg

What's the better cross-DE way to disable the screensaver in Linux? I found [something](http://program-nix.blogspot.ro/2010/08/python-inhibiting-gnome-screensaver.html) here but it's only for gnome-screensaver. I'm wondering if there's any way to simulate a keystroke or some X.Org API to disable screensaver activation.

Comment: possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575528/simulating-key-press-event-using-python-for-linux

Comment: I wouldn't simulate keystrokes. There are only about three or four screensaver packages to begin with, so just find their DBus interfaces (if they exist) and tell them to turn off.

Comment: @Blender But his software will break as soon as someone writes a new screensaver. You're also forgetting about stuff like xfce4-power-manager, which dims the screen (it's not a screensaver itself, but I'm pretty sure that his intetiont is to inhibit that as well).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have been looking into this a while ago and finally ended up using `xdg-screensaver` which I call via `subprocess`.

```
import subprocess

def suspend_screensaver():
    window_id = subprocess.Popen('xwininfo -root | grep xwininfo | cut -d" " -f4', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read().strip()

    #run xdg-screensaver on root window
    subprocess.call(['xdg-screensaver', 'suspend', window_id])

def resume_screensaver(window_id):
    subprocess.Popen('xdg-screensaver resume ' + window_id, shell=True)
```

This is not ideal but apparently there is no other solution that would not involve messing around with DE-specific stuff like `dbus` or `gnome-screensaver-command`.

I don't really like the call to `xwininfo` and wish there was a cleaner way but so far could not find anything better. Another issue with the `xwininfo` approach is that it uses the id of the root window instead of the app window. Using the app window id instead of the root window would remove the need for the `resume_screensaver` method since it would then resume as soon as the window is destroyed.

And if you want to simulate keystrokes here is a naive bash script I have been using for some time. It does require `xdotool` which has to be installed separately.

```
#!/bin/bash
while : 
do
   sleep 200
   nice -n 1 xdotool key shift
   echo .
done
```

---

### UPDATE

After having used the python solution above for over a year, it was found to occasionally create zombie processes and/or too many instances of `xdg-screensaver`, so after digging around, I found a simpler alternative which is ***Gnome-specific***, but works for me even in a non-Gnome DE (XFCE) since the core Gnome libraries are required by many GTK-based apps even if you don't have a Gnome desktop.

```
import subprocess

def suspend_screensaver():
    'suspend linux screensaver'
    proc = subprocess.Popen('gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled false', shell=True)
    proc.wait()

def resume_screensaver():
    'resume linux screensaver'
    proc = subprocess.Popen('gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver idle-activation-enabled true', shell=True)
    proc.wait()
```

Comment: I really like the `xdotool`-based solution. I find that xdg-screensaver is a bunch of hacks dumped into a single poorly-designed script, while sending fake keypresses actually makes way more sense (since there's no standard way to do it).

Comment: @Hugo: I have indeed found some issues with `xdg-screensaver` and have replaced a while ago the code in my app with another solution which I have added to the original answer.

Comment: That doesn't disable screen blanking, either by dpms, or xfce4-power-manager, regrettably.

Comment: @Hugo: most likely, you are using `xscreensaver` which is the default in xfce. I removed it, and replaced with `gnome-screensaver` and that's why it works for me. It has a much cleaner and aesthetically pleasing look but may also pull extra dependencies.

Comment: No, I'm quite cleary **not** using xscreensaver, since I very cleary stated I'm using `xfce4-power-manager` for screen blanking (dimming, then blanking, actually). `xscreensaver` is way too much bloat in comparison, and `gnome-screensaver` is even worse.

Comment: Then you might have luck with something along the lines of `xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/inactivity-on-ac -n -t uint -s 0`,  `xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/inactivity-on-battery -n -t uint -s 0` *or* `xset -dpms && xset s noblank && xset s off`. Have not tried either.

Comment: @Hugo As ccpizza mentioned, if you are using XFCE then you can use `xset -dpms; xset s off` to disable the screensaver then `xset +dpms; xset s default` to enable it. That is exactly what xdg-screensaver would be doing (without all the crud).

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old, but there is a more modern answer to it: now most DE on linux use dbus to communicate, and you can use this:

**in shell, using kde tools:**

```
qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.Inhibit "myapps" "because I want it"
```

this dbus call will return a cookie (a number) that will be needed to uninhibit the screesaver:

```
qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.UnInhibit $COOKIE
```

In python, it will be something like

```
import dbus

bus = dbus.SessionBus()
saver = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver', '/ScreenSaver')
saver_interface = dbus.Interface(saver, dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver')

# now we can inhibit the screensaver
cookie=saver_interface.Inhibit("myapps", "because I want it")


# we can also restore it
saver_interface.UnInhibit(cookie)
```

Comment: Yeah, now you can even inhibit power management with dbus. Things have changed since I asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

### Discussion

TLDR; there aren't any cross-DE ways to inhibit the screensaver with pure Python. However the question also asked about doing so with Linux (presumably from the shell). To be clear, there aren't any particularly good cross-DE ways to do so in Linux, but at least there is potential. You probably want to use the hackish `xdg-screensaver` shell script.

This is a topic I've spent some time on. I wasn't happy with any of the solutions out there, so after playing around with some homebrew tools, I ended up modifying the caffeine project to suit my needs and have been using it happily ever since. I'll summarize some of what I've learned in the process.

In case you aren't familiar with it, I'd recommend checking out caffeine (Launchpad PPA @ https://launchpad.net/~caffeine-developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

The caffeine project *mostly* consists of the following scripts: `caffeine-screensaver` `caffeine` `caffeine-indicator` `caffeinate`

`caffeine` and `caffeine-indicator` are written in Python 3 whereas `caffeine-screensaver` is a rebranded `xdg-screensaver` written in shell script.

The first half of **ccpizza**'s answer is great as it is cross-DE and very similar to caffeine's implementation. I haven't had any issues with xdg-screensaver zombie processes but I'm sure it could be remedied if I better knew the use-case or the conditions under which it was occurring. Just a FYI that running `xdg-screensaver suspend ROOT_WINDOW_ID` will background a tracking process and leave it running indefinitely (until it is resumed).

If you're interested in implementing a truly cross-DE solution then I would strongly recommend examining the aforementioned `xdg-screensaver`/`caffeine-screensaver`. The many forks of [lightsOn](https://github.com/iye/lightsOn/network) are ripe as well.

`xdg-screensaver` detects the desktop environment (KDE, Gnome, XFCE, LXDE, xscreensaver, or gnome-screensaver) and acts accordingly. For the `xdg-screensaver suspend` command, it runs `xset -dpms` to disable DPMS, DE-specific commands, then watches the supplied window ID for it's duration. If the window disappears, the resume command is run and xdg-screensaver exits. The `xdg-screensaver resume` command consists of `xset +dpms` (only if DPMS was originally enabled) then the DE-specific commands.

Note that xdg-screensaver will only track the supplied window ID if xprop is available (it's part of x11-utils, so it should be). To track the window, it backgrounds `xprop -id WINDOW_ID -spy` to monitor the window for changes. It stores the PID of the aforemention process along with window ID in a lockfile to reference upon suspend and resume. The original state of DPMS is referenced in a separate lockfile. The lockfiles should ensure there are no duplicate processes.

The script is a complete mess, so I empathize with anyone unfortunate enough to use it, but I haven't encountered any issues. You probably don't want to reinvent the wheel so if you are creating something for public consumption then I'd recommend you just co-opt it. If you're creating something for personal use, then just dig through it and use the commands specific to your DE.

**ccpizza** suggesting using `subprocess.Popen('xwininfo -root | grep xwininfo | cut -d" " -f4', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read().strip()` to get the desktop's root window ID. Using the desktop's root window ID with `xdg-screensaver suspend` will disable the desktop's screensaver indefinitely. Using a specific window's ID will disable the desktop's screensaver for the duration of the window.

---

### Shell Script

To determine the **active window ID**, you can run the following:

```
xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW | awk -F '[ ,]' '{print $5}'
```

To determine the **root window ID**, you can run the following:

```
xwininfo -root | awk '/^xwininfo: Window id: / {print $4}'
```

To determine the **screensaver timeout**, you can run the following:

```
xset q | awk '/^  timeout: / {print $2}'
```

*NOTE: the result will be 0 if the screensaver is disabled*

To determine **whether DPMS is enabled or disabled**, you can run the following:

```
xset q | awk '/^  DPMS is / {print tolower($3)}'
```

---

### Python Script

There are pure Python options as well. The `Xlib` module is great for this, as is `ewmh` (which is a wrapper around Xlib).

To determine the **active window ID with ewmh**:

```
active_id = hex(ewmh.EWMH().getActiveWindow().id)
```

To determine the **root window ID with ewmh**:

```
root_id = hex(ewmh.EWMH().root.id)
```

To determine the **active window ID with Xlib**:

```
from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib.X import AnyPropertyType

active_id = hex(Display().screen().root.get_full_property(Display().get_atom('_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW'), AnyPropertyType).value[0])
```

To determine the **root window ID with Xlib**:

```
from Xlib.display import Display
root_id = hex(Display().screen().root.id)
```

To determine the **screensaver timeout with Xlib**:

```
from Xlib.display import Display
timeout = Display().get_screen_saver().timeout
```