# Simulate Key Press event in Python on Intel Edison

Tags: python, linux, events, keypress, intel-edison

I am trying to get an existing Python script which starts playing a song via [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html) to be able to interact with its keyboard input functionality (e.g. space to play/pause, arrow keys to fast forward/rewind).

I have tried using [python-uinput](http://tjjr.fi/sw/python-uinput/), but running the example keyboard script does nothing (no errors). I executed `modprobe input` before running too.

I also tried [python-evdev](https://github.com/gvalkov/python-evdev) (after installing some other necessary dependencies), ran its example code and again there was no output, and also no errors.

I'm wondering if there is something that's causing both of these to not work the way they would on a full Linux build? Just a thought; really not sure what's going on. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

**I'm also open to other suggestions on how to control mplayer from a python script, besides simulating keyboard events.**

[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575528/simulating-key-press-event-using-python-for-linux)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might have installed mplayer. If not please refer [Intel Communities](https://communities.intel.com/thread/75473?start=0&tstart=0). If you come across this error

`make: install: Command not found
Makefile:910: recipe for target 'install-dirs' failed
make: *** [install-dirs] Error 127`

Install coreutils using [AlexT's repo](http://alextgalileo.altervista.org/edison-package-repo-configuration-instructions.html).

`#opkg install coreutils`

Also for [python-evdev](https://github.com/gvalkov/python-evdev),

`#opkg install python-pip
 #pip install evdev
 #python -m evdev.evtest`

Answer (score 0):

For uinput add `import time` at the top and `time.sleep(0.5)` before key press.

Worked for me today on a project using uinput

Sample:

```
import time
import uinput

device = uinput.Device([
    uinput.KEY_LEFTALT,
    uinput.KEY_TAB,
    ])

time.sleep(0.5)

device.emit_combo([
    uinput.KEY_LEFTALT,
    uinput.KEY_TAB,
    ])
```