# How can I send the Ctrl key to my terminal with subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm writing a script that will open up tmux in my terminal and split the windows. To do that I need to send tmux, Ctrl + b and % to the terminal.

```
def make_win():
    subprocess.call('tmux', shell=True)
    subprocess.call('Ctrl', 'b', shell=True)
    subprocess.call('%', shell=True)
```

The 'Ctrl' and 'b' keys need to be held down/clicked at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `subprocess` per se has no capabilities to send key pressed events (to the sub-process or to any other process). You will need to adopt a [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575528/simulating-key-press-event-using-python-for-linux) | [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714072/simulate-keystroke-in-linux-with-python).

Comment: Thankyou for this I found both of those links very helpful. :)